# using swift3 how to upload a video on youtube using alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift3

Currently, I am using Alamofire upload function to upload the video on youtube.but I am getting an error message from the response.
 I am using the code as below.

var videodata: NSData?

```
func postVideoToYouTube(token: String, callback: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){

    let videoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType: "mp4")
    do{
        videodata = try NSData(contentsOfFile: videoPath!, options:NSData.ReadingOptions.alwaysMapped)
    }
    catch _ {
        videodata = nil
        return
    }
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [ "auth-token": "\(String(describing: userToken))" ]
    let URL = try! URLRequest(url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=id", method: .post, headers: headers)

    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(videodata! as Data, withName: "video", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")
    },
        with: URL,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in

                    print("Upload Progress:%d", Progress)

                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response.request!)  // original URL request
                    print(response.response!) // URL response
                    print(response.data!)     // server data
                    print(response.result)

                    if((response.result.value) != nil) {
                        print("response is",response)
                        callback(true)
                    } else {
                        print("else")
                        callback(false)
                    }
                }
            case .failure( _):
                break
            }
    })

}
```

I am getting an error as below.

```
The response is SUCCESS: {
    error =     {
        code = 401;
        errors =         (
                        {
                domain = global;
                location = Authorization;
                locationType = header;
                message = "Login Required";
                reason = required;
            }
        );
        message = "Login Required";
    };
}
```

Actually, I do not know why it is showing this error message but I tried to login with Gmail and it is not working.Hope anybody can help me.

Comment: are you passing userToken value in 'auth-token'?

Comment: There is no HTTP header `auth-token`. Usually it's `Authorization`. Are you sure about that header?

Comment: As an aside, once you get this done, I might be inclined to use background session for the upload (which is admittedly a hassle with Alamofire) because uploads of videos can sometimes take a long time and you might not want the app to be dependent upon the user staying in the app during the upload process.